# Title and author of short SF story about an alien romantic date

Tags: story-identification

Can anybody point me to the original story:

Two individuals are having a romantic dinner, one of them thinking how to 'score' during the subsequent hours. The reader is initially made believe that the individuals are humans, but towards the end it turns out they are aliens and their dinner consists of humans.
I think they look at humans like humans look at cattle.

I read the story during mid-80s, but it is probably considerably older.

Comment: Any details about when/where you might have read this would be very helpful.

Comment: Anything at (TVTropes warning) http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ToServeMan look reasonable?

Comment: I doubt this is it, but the Larry Niven story "Assimilating Our Culture, That's What They're Doing!" may be relevant. The ending is "They'll take Campbell's, and like it!" if that rings a bell.